# What is the difference between \hspace*{\fill} and \hfill?

Tags: spacing, lengths

In the [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir) manual on page 183 ,this example is given:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\hspace*{\fill}
{ILLUSTRATION 1} \hfill {ILLUSTRATION 2}
\hspace*{\fill}
\caption{Example float with two illustrations}
\label{fig:mult1}
\end{figure}
```

I have tried to figure out, what the difference between `\hspace*{\fill}` and `\hfill` is!?

The [`\hfill` definition](http://www.tug.org/tutorials/latex2e/%245chfill.html) and [`\hspace` definition](http://www.tug.org/tutorials/latex2e/%245chspace.html) did not help me much.

Comment: You can use: `a\hfill b\hfill \hspace{0.01mm} `

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Using your code snippet as an example, `\centering` only has an impact on the `\caption`. However,

```
\hspace*{\fill}
{ILLUSTRATION 1} \hfill {ILLUSTRATION 2}
\hspace*{\fill}
```

is meant to set `ILLUSTRATION 1` and `ILLUSTRATION 2` even distributed across `\textwidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\hspace*{\fill}
{ILLUSTRATION 1} \hfill {ILLUSTRATION 2}
\hspace*{\fill}
\caption{Example float with two illustrations}
\label{fig:mult1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, replacing `\hspace*{\fill}` with `\hfill`, the space from the right margin is "gobbled":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\hfill%\hspace*{\fill}
{ILLUSTRATION 1} \hfill {ILLUSTRATION 2}%
\hfill%\hspace*{\fill}
\caption{Example float with two illustrations}
\label{fig:mult1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

giving value to the command definition for `\hspace*`:

> LaTeX removes horizontal space that comes at the end of a line. If you don't want LaTeX to remove this space, include the optional `*` argument. Then the space is never removed.

An alternative to use if `\hfill` is more intuitive than `\hspace*{\fill}`, is to insert dummy text (like `\null` or `\mbox{}`) at the (start and) end of the line. That way the `\hfill` will always have "something to infinitely stretch against":

```
\null\hfill%
{ILLUSTRATION 1} \hfill {ILLUSTRATION 2}%
\hfill\null%
```

In the above examples, [`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) merely highlighted the text block.

Comment: Is `\hspace{\fill}` and `\hfill` the same? Why is there no `\hfill*`?

Comment: Why do you need `\null` at the start of the line?  I can't see the difference with or without.

Comment: @adl: You don't need it at the start of the line. It just provides for symmetrical coding.

Answer (score 14):

There is a very good discussion and answers at [What is the difference between 'fil' and 'fill'?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/what-is-the-difference-between-fil-and-fill).

As related to the specifics in your question `\hfill` is a TeX primitive that expands to,

```
 \hfill = \hskip 0pt plus 1fill minus 0pt
```

whereas  `\hspace*{\fill}`, is a LaTeX macro, which leaves a space equal to a `1fill`. The star version of the command is used if the glue is to be inserted at the beginning of a line.