# Right-aligning using \strut and \hfill, inconsistent results

Tags: horizontal-alignment, strut

I'm writing an exam and using a `\marks` macro with `\strut` and `\hfill`  to show the marks available for each question right-aligned, bold and in square brackets. But sometimes it doesn't put it on the right! In the MWE output, 1 and 4 are correct, 2 and 3 are wrong. In the source, 1 and 3 have no space before the `\marks`, 2 and 4 do.

I'm using `\strut` thanks to the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158583/hfill-doesnt-work-on-new-line).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\renewcommand{\marks}[1]{\strut\hfill\textbf{[#1]}}

\begin{document}

Sample Exam!

\begin{enumerate}
\item xx3 x xxxxxx x x x x xxx x x x x x x xx x x x x x xxxx x x x xx x xxxxxxx xxx x x x x xx\marks{5}
\item xx3 x xxxxxx x x x x xxx x x x x x x xx x x x x x xxxx x x x xx x xxxxxxx xxx x x x x xx \marks{5}
\item xxx4 x xxxxxx x x x x xxx x x x x x x xx x x x x x xxxx x x x xx x xxxxxxx xxx x x x x xx\marks{5}
\item xxx4 x xxxxxx x x x x xxx x x x x x x xx x x x x x xxxx x x x xx x xxxxxxx xxx x x x x xx \marks{5}


\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not really related to your question, but are you aware of the [``exam`` class](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam)? It's a great tool to produce exams in LaTeX.

Comment: Do not redefine a command like \marks unless you *really* know what you are doing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowing from D. E. Knuth himself (look for “Bourbaki” in the index of the TeXbook):

```latex
\newcommand{\Marks}[1]{{% note the additional brace
  \unskip % remove a possible space
  \nolinebreak % no break here
  \hfil % fill
  \penalty50 % a possible break point here
  \hspace{0.5em}% minimum separation
  \mbox{}% something that cannot be discarded
  \nolinebreak % no break here
  \hfil % fill
  \textbf{[#1]}% the marks
  \parfillskip=0pt % no fill by \par
  \finalhyphendemerits=0 % a hyphen on the line above the marks is good
  \par % end the paragraph
}}
```

A line break can be taken at `\penalty50`, which would remove the following `\hspace{0.5em}`.

The spaces before the `%` signs in the code are *wanted*.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\newcommand{\Marks}[1]{{% note the additional brace
  \unskip % remove a possible space
  \nolinebreak % no break here
  \hfil % fill
  \penalty50 % a possible break point here
  \hspace{0.5em}% minimum separation
  \mbox{}% something that cannot be discarded
  \nolinebreak % no break here
  \hfil % fill
  [#1]% the marks
  \parfillskip=0pt % no fill by \par
  \finalhyphendemerits=0 % a hyphen on the line above the marks is good
  \par % end the paragraph
}}

\begin{document}

Sample Exam!

\begin{enumerate}
\item xx3 x xxxxxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx\Marks{5}
\item xx3 x xxxxxx x x x x xxx x x x x x x xx x x x x x xxxx x x x xx x xxxxxxx xxx x x x x xx \Marks{5}
\item xxx4 x xxxxxx x x x x xxx x x x x x x xx x x x x x xxxx x x x xx x xxxxxxx xxx x x x x xx\Marks{5}
\item xxx4 x xxxxxx x x x x xxx x x x x x x xx x x x x x xxxx x x x xx x xxxxxxx xxx x x x x xx \Marks{5}


\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

***Don't*** redefine commands you don't know about, in this case the primitive command `\marks`.

[image]

Try the solution proposed in the other answer with

```
\item xx3 x xxxxxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx\Marks{5}
```

and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Thanks, yes this works better with your final example. Changed my accepted answer to this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce an unbreakable space `~` with a preceding `\null` to form a new line when a single line is not wide enough.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\renewcommand{\marks}[1]{\null~\hfill\textbf{[#1]}}

\begin{document}

Sample Exam!

\begin{enumerate}
\item xx3 x xxxxxx x x x x xxx x x x x x x xx x x x x x xxxx x x x xx x xxxxxxx xxx x x x x xx\marks{5}
\item xx3 x xxxxxx x x x x xxx x x x x x x xx x x x x x xxxx x x x xx x xxxxxxx xxx x x x x xx \marks{5}
\item xxx4 x xxxxxx x x x x xxx x x x x x x xx x x x x x xxxx x x x xx x xxxxxxx xxx x x x x xx\marks{5}
\item xxx4 x xxxxxx x x x x xxx x x x x x x xx x x x x x xxxx x x x xx x xxxxxxx xxx x x x x xx \marks{5}    
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks, this works, and it works in my real exam too. I had never heard of `\null` before and after reading https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24919/what-is-null-and-when-do-we-need-to-use-it/24921 I am confused, but it works!

Comment: Sorry, but this is too simplistic.