# Center two images using multiple \hfills

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I have two images that I want to show side by side, horizontally centered. I would like to distribute the remaining horizontal space evenly in three parts: To the left of the first image, between the images, and after the second image.
So I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\hfill
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

However the last `\hfill` is ignored:

[image: screenshot]

Why is this happening? How can I achieve the desired result ?

Comment: I was typing an answer when this question got closed. Anyway, if you want to understand all the glue on the line, try the following (as a bare "paragraph", without `\centering` or the `figure` environment): `\noindent\null\hfill\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}\hfill\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}\hfill\null`. You can play around with removing various parts of it and see what happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An extra `\hfill` will do it.  Also, `\centering` not needed in this case.  And, technically speaking, one should end lines with `%` signs, in order to avoid the insertion of small spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[H]
%\centering
\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}%
\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}%
\hfill%
\hfill%
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately (and more naturally), `\hfil` all around will do it with a single.  However, in this case, `\centering` *cannot* be used, without the addition of an `\hfilneg` (negative infinite glue) at the beginning of the line (or else added asymmetric `\hfil`s).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[H]
%\centering\hfilneg
\hfil%
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}%
\hfil%
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}%
\hfil%
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Point taken re. `\centering` and %. However: In the solution involving `\hfill`, why is the additional `\hfill` needed? And why it is NOT needed if using `\hfil` instead ?

Comment: @Grodriguez I can't offer a technical explanation, other than to say that some types of alignments come with pre-built fils (or anti-fils that can absorb a fil) at the beginning and end of line, and so any fils you add are competing with these.

Comment: @Grodriguez pp. 71-72 of Knuth's The TeXbook describes some of these glues, `\hfil`, `\hfill`, `\hss`,  and `\hfilneg`.

Comment: Adding a `\null` or a `\strut` instead of a second `\hfill` also seems to do the trick. [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45952/78415) mentions that "LaTeX removes horizontal space at the end of a line".

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively with `\centering` and `\hfil` between images:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\hfil
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you -- but why does this work with only one single `\hfill` ?

Comment: not with `\hfill` (double l, i.e:`ll`) but with `hfil` (single `l`) and centering. difference between them is explained in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/what-is-the-difference-between-fil-and-fill

Comment: Yes, I actually meant `\hfil` (typo in my comment). I also read the question you linked but I still don't understand -- why this works in this specific case?

Comment: I'm affray that I'm not able to answer better as it is explained in given link :(. Simplified: power of `\hfil` is smaller than of `hfill` ... it move images apart so, that in centering environment the horizontal empty space is equal distributed around images. With `\hfill` between images would move them to left and right text border.