# \hspace not even

Tags: spacing

I want to put 3 figures in one line and I adjust the horizontal position of figures using `\hspace{}`. The problem is that when I set the spacing to -16pt, i.e. `\hspace{-16pt}`, the figure does not move left. When I set the spacing to -17pt, `\hspace{-17pt}`, the figure moves to the left a lot. I tried spacing -15pt, -14pt, ..., -1pt, 0pt. The figure's position is the same as `\hspace{-16pt}`.

The example code is as follows:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \hspace{-15pt}
        \includegraphics[width=63mm]{images/1.pdf}\par 
        \hspace{-15pt}
        \includegraphics[width=63mm]{images/2.pdf}\par 
        \hspace{-15pt}
        \includegraphics[width=63mm]{images/3.pdf}\par
    \end{multicols}

\end{figure*}
```

Why does this happen? How to make appropriate adjustment? I do need the figure to move to the left a little bit, but not that much.

Comment: There are almost certainly good reasons for your problem, but without any actual code to test, it is hard to guess what you are doing 'wrong'.  Please post a complete, but [minimal(!) example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: Note (for future reference): you are missing `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` (to make the example **complete**); and people don't have your 3 PDFs in your `images/` directory, so the example can't be compiled (a good substitute is to load the package `mwe` and use, say, its `example-image.png`).

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between \hspace*{\fill} and \hfill?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45948/5764)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the start of a line TeX ignores spaces. The star form is needed: `\hspace*{-15pt}`.