# Why does \hspace*{\fill} need \null for desired output?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I was trying to centre some math within an enumerate list, without a lineskip.

I eventually found [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45948/what-is-the-difference-between-hspace-fill-and-hfill) of `\hfill` vs `\hspace*{\fill}` which seems to suggest that using `\hspace*{\hfill}` will avoid space on the RHS being gobbled up; however, when I implement it, I don't get any difference in rendering between the two.

NB: I resolved the specific issue by including a `\null`, but would like to know what misunderstanding is leading me to expect different output,

i.e. **why does `\hspace*{\hfill}` still require `\null` to not gobble right-hand-side space?**

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \hspace*{\fill} %
            % Some math content
            $y(x) = a_o + a_1 (x-k) + a_2(x-k)^2 + a_3(x-k)^3 + a_4(x-k)^4$ 
            %
            \hspace*{\fill}
    %
    \item \hspace*{\fill} %
            % Some math content
            $y(x) = a_o + a_1 (x-k) + a_2(x-k)^2 + a_3(x-k)^3 + a_4(x-k)^4$
            %
            \hspace*{\fill}\null
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Notice the difference between the first line (without `\null`) and the second line (with `\null`):

[image]

Comment: Could s/o add more appropriate tags? Seems to me this one alone won't show up very well in searches including `\hfill` or `\hspace`, but they don't appear as options...

Comment: The final `\null` serves no purpose.

Comment: @egreg How can you say that without explaining the difference that Rax is seeing in the output with or without that control sequence.

Comment: @Kaz Remove `\null` and you'll see that the output is exactly the same.

Comment: @Kaz this point is addressed by David C.'s answer (specifically, there is no `item` following the final `\hspace{\fill}`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's more normal in latex to use `\centering` or the `center` environment to centre things, however the reason that you need the `\null` is  `\item` if used in horizontal mode removes horizontal space at the end of the previous paragraph.

If you remove the `%` these two lines are set the same way

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \hspace*{\fill} %
            % Some math content
            $y(x) = a_o + a_1 (x-k) + a_2(x-k)^2 + a_3(x-k)^3 + a_4(x-k)^4$ 
            %
            \hspace*{\fill}
    % > If you remove this % (or add a line above it) both will render the same.
    \item \hspace*{\fill} %
            % Some math content
            $y(x) = a_o + a_1 (x-k) + a_2(x-k)^2 + a_3(x-k)^3 + a_4(x-k)^4$
            %
            \hspace*{\fill}\null
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Note also the usage `\hspace*{\fill} %` also breaks the centering as it adds fill glue plus one word space, you probably intended `\hspace*{\fill}%`

Comment: Amazing: you pointed out several things here that I wasn't registering even though I "knew" them - thank you for not only addressing the question but pointing out related issues (extra spaces due to poor use of `%` etc). Best, RA

Comment: More precisely, when used in horizontal mode `\item` will remove three globs of glue (see `latex.ltx`, ll. 4671–4673), substituting the `\parfillskip` glue for them (`0pt plus 1fil`, weaker than `\fill`); in @RaxAdaam’s example these are the `\fill` glue, the null skip that `\hspace*` adds after it, and the glue due to the uncommented end-of-line after `\hspace*{\fill}`.  Incidentally, `\endtrivlist` in horizontal mode removes only two globs (line 4625), and that’s why, if you remove the `\null` in the second item, the `\fill` survives notwithstanding (who knows whether egreg knew this… ;-) .

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti yes I noticed that while checking for this answer, but decided the extra information wasn't clarifying the main point about the fact that `\null` is guarding from `\unskip` :-)

Comment: Actually, the main reason for which I added my comment was to tease you about @egreg… :-)  (“@” intentionally added.)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti who's egreg?

Answer (score 4):

First of all:

- `\hspace*{\fill} %` generates `\hfill` folowed by *space* (note the space before percent character) but direct `\hfill` does not this.
- `\hspace*` does protection at the start of the line, no at its end.
- TeX (no LaTeX!) removes the last glue when `\par` is followed.
- LaTeX's `\item` macro does `\unskip\unskip\par` when it is processed in horizontal mode.
- LaTeX's `\hspace*{\fill}` macro puts `\vrule width0pt \hfill \hskip0pt` into horizontal metarilal.

The `\hspace*{\fill} %` followed by `\item` removes your unwanted space before percent character using fist `\unskip`, then removes `\hskip0pt` using second `\unskip` and finally `\par` removes `\hfill`. This is the reason why your `\hspace*{\fill} %` disappears when it is followed by `\item`.