# I don't know how to create a Horizontal blank spaces starting a new line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line

I want to create a line which exists horizontal blank spaces at start of the line. The effect like this:
[image]

However, the line must have one character when use ***\hfill***  like this:

```
a\hfill Your-name-here
```

When I removed the a, the effect disappear and the code like this:

```
\hfill Your-name-here
```

I don't know how to solve the problem. Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: you want an horizontal space, or right alignment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Typically, you'll want to include a minimal working example, which will help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an empty box in front of `\hfill`

```
\mbox{}\hfill Your-name-here
```

Comment: Please, can you explain better your solution? Thank you.

Comment: `\mbox` is LaTeX specific. But the question is not LaTeX specific.

Answer (score 1):

If you are at the beginning of the paragraph, then `\hfill text` works. But if you are after `\hfil\break` at the next line on the paragraph, then `\hfill text` does not work because `\hfill` is discardable item, it is removed after previous break. So, you have to do `\hfil\break \null\hfill text`. If you create a macro, then you can do `\def\yourmacro{\leavevmode\null\hfill}` and use `\yourmacro text`. This macro works in any context (in vertical mode, it starts horizontal mode first).

Comment: Thanks, I will learn it later.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `\hfill`, use `\hspace{\fill}`. I recommend to have a look at
[What is the difference between \hspace*{\fill} and \hfill?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45948/what-is-the-difference-between-hspace-fill-and-hfill)

However, from your question,  I'm wondering if you don't just want right aligned text, do you?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\hspace{\fill}some text preceded by stretchable horizontal space
\begin{flushright}
some right aligned text
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\flushright` also inserts vertical space.  If he doesn't want that, he can use `\hbox to\linewidth{\hfill Your text}`.

Comment: flushrigt is LaTeX specific. But the question is not LaTeX specific.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii Indeed, I asked if (and not assumed that) the OP wants the horizontal space to achieve right-alignment. My MWE presents both.

Comment: I just want one of lines to right aligned, and very detail explaination. Thanks