# Using \hfill in a beamer \frametitle in the wuerzburg theme

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I'm using a [set of beautiful beamer templates](http://www.cgogolin.de/Computer.html) developed by Christian Gogolin and I'm struggling to get the desired effect using the `\hfill` command in `\frametitle{}` in order to have a beamer button **aligned completely to the right in the frame title.**

Here is a MWE, using Gogolin's own *wuerzburg* beamer outer theme:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={x11names,svgnames,dvipsnames}]{beamer} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\useoutertheme[nofootline]{wuerzburg}
\usecolortheme{shark}
%\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][none] % uncommenting this gives proper placement but overrides the frametitle definition of the outer theme. 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This is the frame title \hfill \beamergotobutton{right}}
Some text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: <code>Example frame with unaligned button</code>]

The "right" beamer button is not aligned right as expected; its absolute position also changes based on the lenght of the title text.

I tried to implement the advice given [on google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/latexusersgroup/HyAqv6sIgYY): using `\frametitle{Title \hspace{1 filll} Logo}` (`1 filll` or `1 fill` both do not work).

Using `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][none]` gives proper placement but overrides the frametitle definition of the outer theme.

I imagine that the fix would involve the definition of `frametitle` template in the *wuerzburg* theme:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{wuerzburg theme}[1][left]
{
  \nointerlineskip
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{\vskip0.5ex}{%
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitletopmshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
    \nointerlineskip%
  }%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,#1,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1.7ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fte#1\endcsname\fi%
    \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1.3ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \nointerlineskip
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{%
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitlebottomshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}%
    \vskip-1.5pt%
  }%
}
```

But I can't figure out what goes wrong here: the text width seems to be correct and I don't understand the role of `\strut\par` around `\insertframetitle`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `\hspace{0pt plus 1 filll}` instead of `\hfill`:

```
\frametitle{This is the frame title \hspace{0pt plus 1 filll}  \beamergotobutton{right}}
```

---

The environment `beamercolorbox`has predefined left and right margins which are defined with the skip `0pt plus 1fill`. If you are using `\hfill` the word is centered for the right part. To show the behaviour you can use the following mwe:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\parindent0pt
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\null Word \hfill word \par


\null Word \hfill word \hfill\null\par

\null\hspace{0pt plus 1fill} Word \hfill word \hspace{0pt plus 1fill}\null\par

\null\hspace{0pt plus 1fill} Word \hspace{0pt plus 1filll} word \hspace{0pt plus 1fill}\null\par
\end{document}
```

> [image]

egreg wrote an answer to this special registers: [What is the difference between 'fil' and 'fill'?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/what-is-the-difference-between-fil-and-fill)

Comment: Well, that was fast! Thank you. I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed to.

Comment: Just for curiosity, would you mind explaining the difference between the two?

Comment: @MatteoS: Does the edit help?