# Implicit \hfil at the end of each paragraph?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tex-core, paragraphs, plain-tex

Why do `Alpha \hfil\ Omega\par` and `Alpha \hfil\ Omega` not flush "Omega" to the right?

Comment: Use `\hfill` instead.

Comment: @Sigur I know that `\hfill` will flush "Omega" to the right but why won't `\hfil` do that, too?

Comment: They have different power of stretchability. `\hfill` is more powerful.

Comment: As to "why": every paragraph has `\parfillskip` glue added to the end of the last line. Normally the value of `\parfillskip` is `0pt plus 1fil`, which exactly balances `\hfil`.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/what-is-the-difference-between-fil-and-fill

Comment: Also: if `\hfil` is not on the last line of the paragraph, then it will only stretch as far as needed after the line has been filled with text.

Comment: @Dan Will `\hfill` do anything different on a line not last in a paragraph?

Comment: May be, you need to say `\parfillskip=0pt plus1fill` (fill .. double el). Then `\hfil` before Omega shrinks to 0pt when it occurs at the last line of the paragraph. But I don't understand why do you need to write \hfil between Alpha and Omega. So, more simple answer: remove \hfil between these words.

Comment: @AngelTsankov By popular demand I have submitted my comments as an answer, expanded to also addresses the question you asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every paragraph has `\parfillskip` glue added to the end of the last line. Normally the value of `\parfillskip` is `0pt plus 1fil`, which exactly balances \hfil. Therfore,

```
Alpha\hfil Omega\par
```

will have equal space before and after "Omega". On the other hand

```
Alpha\hfill Omega\par
```

has infinitely stronger stretch on the left side of "Omega" and so "Omega" is flush with the right edge.

If `\hfil` or `\hfill` is used in the middle of a paragraph, if there is no linebreak forced by the user, one will usually find that TeX fills up the line as full as it can without shrinking any spaces, and then simply stretches `\hfil` or `\hfill` only as much as needed to fill the line. In order to flush the "Omega" to the right edge, one can use either `\hfil` or `\hfil` with a line break right after "Omega":

```
Alpha\hfil Omega\break Beta Gamma
```

If you break the line with `\\` (a natural way to do that) one should use `\hfill`
because `\\` adds `\hfil` (usually).

```
Alpha\hfill Omega\\ Beta Gamma
```

If `\centering`, `\flushleft` or `\raggedright` is in effect, then there will be glue that is added at the end of every line. That glue is usually equivalent to `\hfil`, so one would then also need `\hfill` to ensure "Omega" is at the right.

In summary, to flush "Omega" to the right edge, use `\hfill` before it and put a linebreak (or the end of the paragraph) right after it.

For more details and examples, see Heiko's fine answer.

Answer (score 10):

## First case: `Alpha \hfil\ Omega\par`

An example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=23mm,vmargin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\lip}{\lipsum*[101]\unskip}
\newcommand*{\om}{\textcolor{red}{Omega}}

\begin{document}

\verb|\parfillskip=|\texttt{\the\parfillskip}

1. Alpha \hfil \om\par

2. Alpha \hfill \om\par

3. Alpha \hfil \om\hspace{-\parfillskip}\par

4. Alpha \hfil \om\hspace{-\parfillskip}\null\par

5. Alpha \hfil \om\hspace*{-\parfillskip}\par

6. Alpha \hfil \om{\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}\par}

7. \lip\hfill \om\par

8. \lip~\hfill \om\par

9. \lip\nobreak\hfill~\om\par

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

- The example has reduced the space between "Alpha" and "Omega" to one space and one `\hfil(l)`. If the minimum space should be larger, then I would rather use `\hspace*{2em plus 1fill}`, for example.
- Case 1: At the end of the paragraph TeX also adds a fill component `\parfillskip`. Its `0pt plus 1fil` gets the same space as the `\hfil` before.
- Case 2: The second `l` of `\hfill` overrules `1fil` of `\parfillskip`.
- Case 3: The trick with an added negative `\parfillskip` does not work, because TeX removes a horizontal glue at the end of the paragraph before inserting `\parfillskip`.
- Case 4: `\null` prevents the removal of the previous glue at the end of the paragraph.
- Case 5: Also the space of `\hspace*{...}` is not removed at the end of a paragraph, because the star form sets two glue commands, the second with zero width that can be removed at the end of the paragraph without harm.
- Case 6: `\parfillskip` is locally reset to zero for this paragraph.
- Case 7: At the start of a line `\hfil` is removed.
- Case 8/9: The no-break-space `~` or `\nobreak` prevents a line break at `\hfil`.

Also to be considered: `Omega` could be subject to hyphenation. This can be prevented by `\mbox`. Robuster variants to put `Omega` at the end of a paragraph:

```
~\hfill\mbox{Omega}\par

\hspace*{.5em plus 1fill}\mbox{Omega}\par
```

## Second case: `Alpha \hfil\ Omega` in the middle of a paragraph

If `Omega` should be at the end of a line, then the line should end right after `Omega`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=24.5mm,vmargin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  1. \lipsum*[101]Alpha~\hfil\mbox{\color{red}Omega}\\
  \lipsum[103]

  2. \lipsum*[101]Alpha~\hfill\mbox{\color{red}Omega}\\
  \lipsum[103]

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

- Case 1: `\hfil` is also added by the new line `\\`.
- Case 2: `\hfill` overrules `\hfil` by `\\`.

Comment: Ah! This is advantage of having Heiko here in the site!. Very nice tutorial! +1.