# pagebreaking and `\vfil` in ConTeXt

Tags: page-breaking, context

I am trying to distribute elements vertically across a page:

```
\setupbodyfont [TeX Gyre Pagella, 30pt] % Or something else
\showframe
\starttext
    A \vfil B \vfil C \vfil D \page E \vfil F \page G
\stoptext
```

The bottom elements "D" and "G" do not sit flush at the bottom of their respective text area (as I had expected) but somewhat higher up. The distance between bottom edge of text area and the bottom line of the last element changes with the number of elements. What am I missing?

Comment: Change `\vfil` to `\vfill`: `A \vfill B \vfill C \vfill D`, etc.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/what-is-the-difference-between-fil-and-fill

Comment: OK, the three orders of infinity sound a bit esoteric, but it seems someone has thought about it a lot. I'm out of my depth there. But: even with `\vfill(l)` the D and F don't sit on the bottom line as drawn by `\showframes` but a few mm up. There seems to be some inner margin at the top and the bottom of the text area.