# Move frame content to default position with a beamer color box

Tags: beamer

I'm a relative neophyte to Beamer and LaTeX in general.  I've started developing a custom Beamer template for my department to use and have begun formatting the content of the frames.

The following MWE produces the below slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{this color}{RGB}{0,48,119}
\setbeamercolor*{running text}{fg = this color}

% Other pages
% Frame title
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{}[1][]
{
    \vskip0.1cm%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm, leftskip = 0.005cm, sep=8pt, #1]     {this color}
            \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle\par%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vfill      
}

% Autopopulate date
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\title{Working with a test beamer presentation}

\begin{frame} 
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title goes here}

Here is some content.  I'd like to have it's position as the default.
\begin{itemize}
    \item Including the colorbox probably pushed it down
    \item Can I include the colorbox \textit{AND} move the frame content back up?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Another title}

Yup.  Not centered.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Below is what the frame looks like.  I'd like to move the content of the slide back to the default position.  Can I do that with the inclusion of the color box in the frame?  If not, what can I do to keep the frame title in it's current position and have the content moved back to the center of the frame?

[image]

The title is moved based upon the images used in the custom background/template.  It's position is correct, so there's no way I can change it's location.

Comment: try replace `\vfill` with `\vfil`

Comment: @touhami Wow.  That was easy.  Thanks!

You should add as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Just one tip: When you are developing a theme for a wider audience, try to avoid measurements in absolute units, e.g. `wd=12cm`, but give them in units of `\paperwidth`. This make the theme safe in case someone needs for example a different page geometry, 16:9 ratio, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @samcarter.  I cobbled together the theme from bits and pieces that I found online, rather than writing it outright.  I'm also still in the Beamer/LaTeX learning stage, too, so any information like that is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to replace `\vfill` with `\vfil`

```
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{}[1][]
{
    \vskip0.1cm%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm, leftskip = 0.005cm, sep=8pt, #1]     {this color}
            \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle\par%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vfil%                   % \vfill   replaced   
}
```

For more details see [What is the difference between 'fil' and 'fill'?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/what-is-the-difference-between-fil-and-fill)