# Difference between \hfil and \hfill

Tags: spacing, primitives

I am trying to understand the difference between `\hfil` and `\hfill`. I always thought that these commands were roughly equivalent except that `\hfill` was "stronger" than `\hfil`. As a result, I thought that I could centre a line of text using either of the lines:

```
\hfil Horizontally centred \hfil

\hfill Horizontally centred \hfill
```

It turns out that only the first of these snippets actually horizontally centers the text but I do not understand why.

There is a similar issue with `\vfil` and `\vfill`. My understanding is that `\vfill` can be defined as `\vspace{\fill}`, so it makes sense that you *cannot* vertically center some text using

```
\vfill Vertically centered \vfill
```

because `\vspace` is ignored at the top of the page. By the same reasoning,

```
\vspace*{\fill} Vertically centred\vfill
```

should work and it does, although not quite perfectly.  In a similar way, you can use `\hspace*{\fill}` to horizontally centre text.

Is anyone able to clear explanation of what the differences are between `\hfil` and `\hfill`, and between `\vfil` and `\vfill`? I am aware of the post [What is the difference between 'fil' and 'fill'?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/what-is-the-difference-between-fil-and-fill) but this does not help me.

In trying to understand what is going on I created the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=40mm, paperwidth=80mm,showframe]{geometry}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

  \hfil Horizontally centred \hfil

  \hfill Horizontally centred \hfill

  \hspace*{\fill} Horizontally centred \hfill

  \hfill Horizontally centred \hspace*{\fill}

  \hfil Horizontally centred \hspace*{\fill}

  \newpage

  \vfil Vertically centred\vfil

  \newpage

  \vfill Vertically centred\vfill

  \newpage

  \vspace*{\fill} Vertically centred\vfill

\end{document}
```

which produces the four pages:

[image]

Of course, I know that I can centre text with either

```
\centerline{Horizontally centred}

\begin{center}Horizontally centred\end{center}
```

but that's not what I am asking....although I am not convinced that I know the best way to vertically centre text!

Comment: In my mental picture `\hfil` and friends always need something to push against. So I tend to add struts. AFAIR `\hspace*` automatically adds "stomething to push against

Comment: @daleifb Thanks! That's a very clean explanation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**The first case:** `\hfil Horizontally centred \hfil\par` (the blank line adds `\par`).

When `\par` is processed, the first thing TeX does is `\unskip`, then it adds a very high penalty, so the next added glue `\hskip\parfillskip` is not removed. Since the default value of `\parfillskip` is `0pt plus 1fil`, you get centering. Almost, because you have a space after “centred” that's not removed.

**The second case:** `\hfill text\hfill\par` (the blank line adds `\par`).

This works as before, but now the `\parfillskip` glue is killed by `\hfill`.

**The third case** is essentially the same as the second one.

**The fourth case**: `\hfill Horizontally centred \hspace*{\fill}` almost centers the text (the space after “centred”, remember), because `\unskip` doesn't remove `\hspace*{\fill}` (it internally ends with another glob of glue just for this), because `\parfillskip` glue is killed.

**The fifth case**: the `\hfil` glue at either sides (explicit and provided by `\parfillskip` respectively) are killed by `\hspace*{\fill}`.

How do you achieve centering? With

```
\par{\centering Horizontally centred\par}
```

For vertical centering,

1. you have to kill the `\topskip` glue and the baseline skip glue at the top and the bottom
2. use `\vspace*{\fill}` at the top and `\vfill` (or a more symmetrical `\vspace*{\fill}`) at the bottom.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=40mm, paperwidth=80mm,showframe]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{-\topskip}
\vspace*{\fill}
\nointerlineskip
Vertically centred\par
\nointerlineskip
\vfill

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So, it's all about the glue being killed. So what is the recommended way to vertically centre?

Comment: In the first case is there really a space that is not removed? To me it looks like the difference is actually caused by paragraph indentation since `\noindent\hfil text\hfil` centers the text.

Comment: @Andrew The space preceding `\hfil` is *not* removed: `\unskip` does a single glue removal. Since you set `\parindent` to 0pt, using `\noindent` is redundant.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at a different example where I had the default `\parindent`....

Comment: @Andrew Using `\showoutput` can help a lot to discover the implicitly-added skips, or to see that whatever skip you thought you added was discarded (at the beginning of a line or page) or removed by `\unskip`.