# Why doesn't \hfil work to right align?

Tags: plain-tex

I don't understand why

```
{\bf Title}\hfil A.\ Uthor
\bye
```

and

```
{\bf Title}\hfill A.\ Uthor
\bye
```

do not give the same result. Only `\hfill` works to right align text but there is not other infinity, I would expect both to do.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528920/difference-between-hfil-and-hfill

Comment: It's very similar to the question linked by @celdor: there is `\parfillskip` glue in either case, but its default value is `0pt plus 1fil`, so `\hfil` adds to it, whereas `\hfill` kills it. Shall we close as duplicate?