# Divide empty vertical space for relative placement of text

Tags: spacing

I recently learned that I can center a text vertically in the remaining space on a page by using `\vfill` before and after the text, like so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\ctext#1{\begin{center}\MakeUppercase{#1}\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\vfill
\ctext{center}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

This divides the empty space by 50% before and 50% after the text. Is there a way to generalize this to be able to place text relatively throughout the page? In other words, a command, let's say `\vpfill`, that creates a vertical space which is a percentage of the space that would be left at the end of the page.

```
% First page is exactly as before but using \vpfill intsead of \vfill
\lipsum[1] 
\vpfill{0.5} 
\ctext{center 1}
% \vpfill{0.5} % Unnecessary (?) since 50% of the space remains anyways

\newpage % Second page 
\lipsum[1]
\vpfill{0.4}  % Creates space that is 40% of the remaining empty space
\ctext{center 1}
\vpfill{0.2}  % Creates space that is 20% of the remaining empty space 
\ctext{center 2}
% \vpfill{0.4}  % Unnecessary (?) since 40% of the space remains anyways
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give fractional `fill`s and `fil`s (cf. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21022/48973)) using the primitive `\vskip`. On pages terminated by `\clearpage` (like the last page of a document), a `\vfil` is inserted at the end of the document. Thus, the division you ask for can easily be attained using the following two `\vskip`s.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\vskip 0pt plus 1fil\relax % 40 % of the remaining space.
foo
\vskip 0pt plus .5fil\relax % 20 % of the remaining space.

Bye World!

% \clearpage inserts a \vfil automatically, i.e. another 40 % of the remaining space.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

The ratios you have to calculate to obtain the percentages are the amount of stretch at the place you are considering divided by the total stretch on the page, i.e. `1fil / 2.5fil = 40 %` for the first and the last, `.5fil / 2.5fil = 20 %` for the second `\vskip`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something of that sort. It does not require any packages, but only accepts integers which indicate the percentage of the vertical fill. The usage is

```
\vpfill{<percentage>}
<stuff>
\vrfill
```

This is the MWE, the `geometry` package is only loaded because of its `showframe` option, the purpose of which is to illustrate that this works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\ctext#1{\begin{center}\MakeUppercase{#1}\end{center}}
\newcounter{pft}
\newcommand{\vrfill}{\vfill}
\newcommand\vpfill[1]{\setcounter{pft}{0}%
\loop\ifnum\value{pft}<#1\relax
\vfill\stepcounter{pft}%
\repeat
\renewcommand{\vrfill}{\vpfill{\the\numexpr100-#1}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\vfill
\ctext{center}
\vfill
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\vpfill{25}
\ctext{center}
\vrfill
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\vpfill{60}
\ctext{center}
\vrfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can generalize this to work with permille, or any fractions, if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\ctext#1{\begin{center}\MakeUppercase{#1}\end{center}}
\newcounter{pft}
\newcommand{\vrfill}{\vfill}
\newcommand\vpfill[2][100]{\setcounter{pft}{0}%
\loop\ifnum\value{pft}<#2\relax
\vfill\stepcounter{pft}%
\repeat
\renewcommand{\vrfill}{\vpfill{\the\numexpr#1-#2}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\vfill
\ctext{center}
\vfill
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\vpfill[1000]{333}
\ctext{333/1000 of the remaining space}
\vrfill
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\vpfill[1111]{789}
\ctext{333/1111 of the remaining space}
\vrfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple (cumbersome) solution would be to use `\vfill` multiple times. With this you can get any percentages, depending on how often you repeat `\vfill`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\ctext#1{\begin{center}\MakeUppercase{#1}\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\vfill\vfill        %   40%
\ctext{center 1}
\vfill              %   20%
\ctext{center 2}
\vfill\vfill        %   40%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\ctext#1{\begin{center}\MakeUppercase{#1}\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] 
\vspace{.5\textheight} 
\ctext{center 1}
\newpage 
\lipsum[1]
\vspace{.4\textheight} 
\ctext{center 1}
\vspace{.2\textheight} 
\ctext{center 2}
\end{document}
```

Note that in top of page `\vspace{....}` does not work, but `\vspace*{...}` does.

Comment: I think `\textheight` is the height of the page rather than the empty space, so this is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @Tohiko, Is the height of the text area, not of the whole page, but yes, is not what you asked, I did not read the question carefully, sorry.